# How to dynamically recompile and deploy Java project that a Spring Boot project is dependent upon?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-devtools

I have a Spring Boot Maven project that has Spring Boot DevTools enabled so that when I change code in the project it will automatically get reloaded.
I also have a dependent project that I'm referencing in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.mygroupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>common</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I would also like the same functionality in the dependent project so that when I make a code change in that project, then the parent project will pick up the change dynamically and reload.
Is this possible? With Spring Boot devtools?

Comment: If you make that dependency a maven module, it should work. Whatever, it works with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Using Maven modules worked for me. I was unfamiliar with modules but after looking at some examples I got it to work...making a change in my dependent project now automatically causes the Spring Boot project to refresh and pick up the change.

I found this [guide](https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/multi-module-project-eclipse/) helpful since I was working in Eclipse.

I created a new parent project and made my Spring Boot project and the dependent project as "modules" in the new parent project. I initially tried to make the Spring Boot project the "parent" but that didn't fly...I got into some kind of infinite loop of building when I tried that.